# How can I prevent an error in my Perl script from terminating the script?

Tags: linux, perl, exception, daemon

I have a simple Perl script which runs as a Linux daemon using an infinite loop. It connects to a database every 10 seconds to execute a process.

```
while (1)
{
    # THIS LINE WILL KILL THE SCRIPT IF IT FAILS
    my $DB=DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:server=myserver","user","password");
    . . . do something . . .
    sleep (10);
}
```

I have two questions:

- If the DB is unavailable, how I can keep the script running?
- Can I add an exception handler to send me an email or log an error?

Comment: Note: your script does not connect every ten seconds.  If the average connection takes 1 second, then your script is connecting (on average) every 11 seconds.

Comment: I won't tell if you don't. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This attempts to connect at 10 second intervals, not every 10 seconds, as William Pursell noted:

```
while (1)
{
    # THIS LINE WILL KILL THE SCRIPT IF IT FAILS
    my $DB;
    eval { 
        $DB = DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:server=myserver","user","password");
    };
    if ( my $ex = $@ ) {
        warn $ex;
        next;
    }
    # do something with $DB
    continue {
        sleep 10;
    }
}
```

See also [Object Oriented Exception Handling in Perl, is it worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503189/object-oriented-exception-handling-in-perl-is-it-worth-it) and [How can I cleanly handle error checking in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223367/how-can-i-cleanly-handle-error-checking-in-perl/1223418#1223418)

Comment: I don't think you want to redeclare my $DB inside the eval block.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit puzzled:

```
   my $DB=DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:server=myserver","user","password");
```

should not normally die if it can't connect. Normally it should return an Error Code
instead of a db-handle.  Only if you use RaisError will it die / throw an exception.

```
   my $DB=DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:server=myserver","user","password", 
                        { RaiseError => 1});
```

See the [DBI man-page](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#RaiseError_(boolean,_inherited))

Answer (score 1):

From [Programming Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000271/):

```
sub try (&@) {
     my($try,$catch) = @_;
     eval { &$try };
     if ($@) {
         local $_ = $@;
         &$catch;
     }
}
sub catch (&) { $_[0] }

try {
    die "phooey";
} catch {
    /phooey/ and print "unphooey\n";
};
```